# Why is my threaded process still freezing?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm writing an app using tkinter for the GUI, and I want an indeterminate progress bar to be going back and forth while the main function is running, which sometimes takes a few seconds, depending on user input. Normally, the whole program freeze while the main function is running, so I am trying to establish a threaded process for the progress bar so it moves while main() is doing its thing (both functions are called within`scan_and_display()`).

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from main import main
import graphs
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import threading

root = Tk()

launch_frame = Frame(root)
button_frame = Frame(root)
graph_frame = Frame(root, height=1000, width=1200)


# log directory button/text
logDirButton = Button(master=launch_frame, text='Select log storage location...',
                      command=lambda: get_directory(log_text), width=22)
log_text = Text(master=launch_frame, height=1, width=25)
logDirButton.grid(row=1, column=0)
log_text.grid(row=1, column=1)

# scan directory button/text
dirButton = Button(master=launch_frame, text="Select scan directory...", command=lambda: get_directory(t), width=22)
t = Text(master=launch_frame, height=1, width=25)
dirButton.grid(row=2, column=0)
t.grid(row=2, column=1)

# main scan button
mainButton = Button(master=launch_frame, text="SCAN!", state=DISABLED,
                    width=50, height=10, bg='#27b355')
mainButton.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

# progress bar
progress = Progressbar(launch_frame, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=100, mode='indeterminate')
progress.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

launch_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NW)


def get_directory(text):
    # first clear form if it already has text
    try:
        text.delete("1.0", END)
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
    # store the first directory for later specific reference

    text.insert(END, directory)

    # disable scan button until user has given necessary info to run (log storage location, scan directory)
    enable_scan_button(log_text, t)

    return directory


def enable_scan_button(logText, dirText):
    if logText.get("1.0", END) != '\n' and dirText.get('1.0', END) != '\n':
        mainButton['state'] = NORMAL
        mainButton['command'] = lambda: scan_and_display()
    else:
        mainButton['state'] = DISABLED


def scan_and_display():

    threading.Thread(target=bar_start).start()
    # get scan directory and log directory from text fields
    log_directory = log_text.get("1.0", END)[:-1]
    scan_directory = t.get("1.0", END)[:-1]

    # store the initial scan directory for later reference
    top_dir = scan_directory

    # runs the main scan function. Passes scan_directory and log_directory arguments
    data, scanDate = main(log_directory, scan_directory)
    display(scan_directory, data, scanDate, top_dir)


    def bar_start():
    print("BAR START CALLED")
    progress.start(10)
```

With this setup (and various other configurations I've trieD), the bar still freezes while `main()` is doing it's thing, and I need it to move to indicate to the user that something is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to thread the long-running function, not the progressbar.

```
def scan_and_display():
    # get scan directory and log directory from text fields
    # It's best to do all tkinter calls in the main thread
    log_directory = log_text.get("1.0", END)[:-1]
    scan_directory = t.get("1.0", END)[:-1]
    
    th = threading.Thread(target=bar_start, args=(log_directory, scan_directory))
    th.start()
    progress.start()

def bar_start(log_directory, scan_directory):
    print("BAR START CALLED")
    
    # store the initial scan directory for later reference
    top_dir = scan_directory

    # runs the main scan function. Passes scan_directory and log_directory arguments
    data, scanDate = main(log_directory, scan_directory)
    display(scan_directory, data, scanDate, top_dir)
    
    progress.stop()
```

EDIT: here's a MCVE:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import time
from threading import Thread

def long_running_function(arg1, arg2, result_obj):
    """accept some type of object to store the result in"""
    time.sleep(3) # long running function
    result_obj.append(f'DONE at {int(time.time())}')
    root.event_generate("<<LongRunningFunctionDone>>") # trigger GUI event

def long_func_start():
    x = 'spam'
    y = 'eggs'
    t = Thread(target=long_running_function, args=(x,y,data))
    t.start()
    result.config(text='awaiting result')
    progress.start()

def long_func_end(event=None):
    progress.stop()
    result.config(text=f"process finished with result:\n{data[-1]}")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

btn = tk.Button(root, text='start long function', command=long_func_start)
btn.pack()

progress = Progressbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=100, mode='indeterminate')
progress.pack()

result = tk.Label(root, text='---')
result.pack()

root.bind("<<LongRunningFunctionDone>>", long_func_end) # tell GUI what to do when thread ends
data = [] # something to store data

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Two follow-up questions if you don't mind:
1) How can I get the return values from my main() function if it's threaded?
2) Why is this the case? Why can the progressbar not be the threaded function?

Comment: 1) There's many ways, what's best will depend on what you want to do with it. The easiest is probably to just set an attribute of some object. If you want the GUI to react to the main function being done you'll probably want to use event_generate to notify the GUI. 2) It probably can be, that's a minor thing. The big issue in your code was that the main function was not threaded.

Comment: @TravisThompson edited to add an example.